# on.click remove part of any url in a <div> and then load it

Tags: javascript, wordpress, redirect, relocation

I want to remove /groups/ from any url in my  when a user clicks it

The backstory is that i have a wordpress widget which displays links to pages (BP groups) and i want users to be sent to pages i've made for each group instead when they click (because i wasnt able to make homepages in buddypress).

I've set the page url's to be the same as the group pages but without /groups/ so if it were removed the widget would send users to my pages instead.

For example a visitor is sent to: 
http://focallocal.org/up-cycling-workshop-with-londons-homeless/
instead of 
http://focallocal.org/groups/up-cycling-workshop-with-londons-homeless/

I've been researching it for ages and this is the best I've been able come up with (I don't speak js):

```
'onclick="location.replace(/groups/,"")'
```

edit requested html:

Close
Events, Groups and Projects
                    
                Newest |
                Active |
                Popular

```
        <ul id="groups-list" class="item-list">
                                <li class="odd public is-admin is-member">
                    <div class="item-avatar">
                        <a href="h t t p://focallocal. org/groups/up-cycling-workshop-with-londons-homeless/" title="Up-cycling Workshop with the Homeless"><img src="h t t p://focallocal. org/wp-content/uploads/group-avatars/4/a4ce0d8153497b96869a9b46e7ff391f-bpthumb.jpg" class="avatar group-4-avatar avatar- photo" width="50" height="50" alt="Group logo of Up-cycling Workshop with the Homeless" title="Up-cycling Workshop with the Homeless"></a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="item-title"><a href="h t t p://focallocal. org/groups/up-cycling-workshop-with-londons-homeless/" title="Up-cycling Workshop with the Homeless">Up-cycling Workshop with the Homeless</a></div>
                        <div class="item-meta">
                            <span class="activity">
                            active 1 week, 1 day ago                                </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>

                                <li class="even public is-admin is-member">
                    <div class="item-avatar">
                        <a href=" h t t p://focallocal. org/groups/public-relations-marketing-and-advertising-team/" title="Public Relations, Marketing and Advertising Team"><img src="http://focallocal.org/wp-content/uploads/group-avatars/2/05196f60439a3fe01b9855f267805180-bpthumb.jpg" class="avatar group-2-avatar avatar- photo" width="50" height="50" alt="Group logo of Public Relations, Marketing and Advertising Team" title="Public Relations, Marketing and Advertising Team"></a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="item-title"><a href="h t t p://focallocal. org/groups/public-relations-marketing-and-advertising-team/" title="Public Relations, Marketing and Advertising Team">Public Relations, Marketing and Advertising Team</a></div>
                        <div class="item-meta">
                            <span class="activity">
                            active 1 month, 3 weeks ago                             </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>

                                <li class="odd 
                        </ul>
        <input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce-groups" name="_wpnonce-groups" value="e2870f6aee"><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/">         <input type="hidden" name="groups_widget_max" id="groups_widget_max" value="300">


    </div>  </div></div><div id="tab_slide_background" class="tab_slide_corners_right"></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Please provide sample HTML code. Do you want to redirect the page on click event or just change the value of the URL in an href of a link, iframe SRC attribute etc..?

Comment: i want to redirect the page on click event, so it would normally load the link in the div but with the code it would load the same link without /groups/ in the URL.

i'll grab some html now, but i thought the problem were more of a general one so it would apply to any link in a <div> that you want to load a different but related url. the links/url's in the widget change dynamically, so i cant just set an ordinary redirect for each.

Comment: if it's useful the site is focallocal.org and the links i want to change are in the sliding bar on the left

Comment: sorry, the html is coming. i have to strip out the url's as i dont have enough reputation yet to post more than 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are using jQuery so you can do this:

```
$('#groups-list a').each(function(){
   var $this = $(this); 
   var href = $this.attr('href');

    href = href.replace('groups/', '');
    $this.attr('href', href);

});
```

you can also do this:

```
 $('#groups-list a[href*="groups"]').each(function(){ this.href = this.href.replace('/groups', '');  });
```

*plain JavaScript*:

```
 var anchors = document.querySelectorAll( "#groups-list a[href*='group']");

for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
var anchor = anchors[i];
anchor.href = anchor.href.replace('/groups', '');

}
```

Comment: that looks perfect to me, but i actually have no idea how to add jQuery to a widget in Wordpress/Buddypress so it'lll take me a while to test it out.

thanks very much!

Comment: Your welcome. I edited the code in my answer to target id not class name for 'groups-list.' You already have jquery on the page. to check, click f12 in chrome. enter 'jQuery' in console. If you want a non-jquery solution,that's easy to implement as well. coming up soon...